# How to COUNT the number of rows where a column matches a column of another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to display the number of posts a user has made, but I have a few different tables and need to match ids and count them.

Something like this:

**Users Table**

```
userid       username      email              regdate

  34          mister      email@some.tld    2013-10-26 12:01:07
```

**Posts Table**

```
postid       creator        post_comment      post_title     status

  1            34          This is comment    Post 1         published
  2            12          This is comment    Post 2         published
  3            34          This is comment    Post 3         pending
  4            25          This is comment    Post 4         published
  5            34          This is comment    Post 5         published
```

Now I already have a query where I select all data about a particular user from the users table:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = $userid");
```

$userid is the id of user that's currently logged in. And this works fine: it selects all relevant information about that user.

But I want to display the number of posts each user makes. I read somewhere on w3schools the SQL `COUNT` function works something like this:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(creator) AS userposts FROM posts WHERE creator=$userid");
```

However, as you can see in table example posted, out of 5 posts, 3 are from user 34 and 1 of these 3 is not published.

I don't know how to make a SQL query that selects all users where userid matches $userid and then selects creator and status from posts and counts the number of posts where creator is $userid and status is published.

This is the output I'm ultimately aiming for:

User mister have 2 posts published.

Comment: use inner join like, `SELECT t1.name, t2.salary
  FROM employee t1 INNER JOIN info t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 2):

In order to get only the number of published posts, you should refactor your condition statement by ANDing `status = 'published'`

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(creator) AS num_posts FROM posts 
WHERE creator=$userid AND status = 'published'");
```

Comment: Yes this works, but now this is separated query, i already have one query to pull user data, can i put this in the same query or i need second one just to count posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(creator) AS userposts FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.creator=u.userid 
WHERE creator=$userid AND status='published'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked in the comment, all in one query:

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(creator) AS userposts FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.creator = u.userid 
WHERE p.creator = $userid AND p.status = 'published'
```